# No value attribute in DatePicker input box

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, datepicker

I have to scrape this site and for that first I need to input data in the fields. I am using Selenium library for the task.

http://nhb.gov.in/OnlineClient/categorywiseallvarietyreport.aspx?enc=3ZOO8K5CzcdC/Yq6HcdIxJ4o5jmAcGG5QGUXX3BlAP4=

The page source has the following code in which I want to input the date in the Date input box.

```
<div style="float: right;">
  <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtdate" type="text" 
id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtdate" style="width:100px;" />
</div>
```

But there happens to be no value attribute and when I try to send input using the `driver.send_keys()` method nothing happens.

This is what I've tried but it doesn't work.

```
date = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtdate")
date.send_keys('09/12/2018')
```

I have even tried mouse operations using `ActionChains` module but the Date input box is not clickable.

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it your way, and it worked for me. Not sure why it's not working with you.

Here's the code I used with what you provided:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://nhb.gov.in/OnlineClient/categorywiseallvarietyreport.aspx?enc=3ZOO8K5CzcdC/Yq6HcdIxJ4o5jmAcGG5QGUXX3BlAP4='

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

date = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtdate")
date.send_keys('09/12/2018')
```

And it worked.

Maybe, try using `.find_element_by_name` and use `"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtdate"` ??

```
url = 'http://nhb.gov.in/OnlineClient/categorywiseallvarietyreport.aspx?enc=3ZOO8K5CzcdC/Yq6HcdIxJ4o5jmAcGG5QGUXX3BlAP4='

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtdate").send_keys('09/12/2018')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, the latter approach it worked..!!

Comment: But I'm facing one more issue, when i try to click the search button it raises error -> **"Element is not clickable at point (414,409)"** with the code `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSearch"]').click()` Could you please help..!

Comment: if there's a popup or something that goes over that, sometimes that'll mess it up. you could try finding that by name though too I think. try changing to `driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch').click()` and see if that works